# Winpdb rpdb2.py no such file or directory

Tags: python, debugging, python-3.7, winpdb

I'm trying to use winpdb reborn 2.0.0.1 for debugging.
When I run command

```
python -m winpdb <my_file>.py
```

debugger window is starting, but there is no code. At the same time that winpdb starts rpdb2 starts in command line and there is an error:

```
C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe: can't open file 'session_manager\..\rpdb2.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

As you may see I'm using Python 3.7 on Windows 10.
I've tried to run it with and without virtual environment, but the error stays the same.